# Errores de libreria al usar IDE Thonny

Tags: python

Estoy trabajando con Python, dí ejecutar y me saltan estos errores. Se que son de bibliotecas que me faltan instalar.

¿Alguno me puede decir cuáles me faltan instalar? ¿O cuál es el problema?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\COMPU\T.P (18).py", line 3, in 
>   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       import matplotlib.colorbar
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py",
>   line 32, in 
>       import matplotlib.artist as martist
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py",
>   line 16, in 
>       from .path import Path
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Usuario.thonny\BundledPython36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py",
>   line 25, in 
>       from . import _path, rcParams
>
> ImportError: DLL load failed: No se puede encontrar el módulo
>   especificado.

Comment: Segun el mensaje de error indica que no has instalado correctamente matplotlib, podrias indicarnos como has intentado instalarlo.

Comment: Estoy usando Thonny para correr el programa y lo instale desde ahi.

Comment: Fui a Tools, Manage Packages, y busque matplotlib y lo instale

Comment: Segun lo que indica no lo ha instalado correctamente, intentalo devuelta y fijate que no te genere ningun mensaje de error en la instalacion.

Comment: Si lo desinstale y lo volvi a instalar y me sigue saltando el error

Comment: Parece que esa ide no es muy buena, nunca habia escuchado de ella, te recomiendo tratar de instalarlo con pip

Comment: Para estar más seguro de la instalación, ve a cmd.exe y escribe: python pip install matplotlib